# get_headers does not give the good result

Tags: php, http-headers, get-headers

I'm trying to get the headers from several URL with `get_headers().`

It's working correctly for some URL but for others I receive `HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found`  as an answer but when I analyze it with a tool such as http://web-sniffer.net/ i see that the real answer is `HTTP/1.0 302 Found`.

When i'm trying with a browser, I'm redirected  to another URL so the good answer should not be the 404 one...

What do I need to change in order to receive the correct header in my script?

For example this URL: http://mp3lg4.tdf-cdn.com/10160/rmc.mp3

Comment: They might be blocking cURL calls. Without the URL, it's difficult to know.

Comment: I added an example of URL.  
Are you sure get_headers is a function of cURL ?

Comment: Is this example URL returns a 404 for you?

Comment: No, `get_headers` doesn't use cURL, but they may have mechanisms to block what appear to be bots using cURL and cURL-like calls. I'm able to do `get_headers` successfully against that URL locally, so it's possible your particular server has been blocked. I'd guess they don't want you downloading their MP3s?

Comment: Ok i fixed it. I was trying to get the header inside a loop. I tried out of the loop and it works perfectly.
So i put a timer between each request and it works... o_O strange...

It's a public radio stream, I just wanted to know the status of it so I can update my playlist :)
Thanks guys !